# Saving Changes OPENXML with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, openxml

Just wondering if someone could point a SharePoint and Powershell newbie in the right direction. We have a problem where some legacy documents in our system have an attachedtemplate which references an old server location that no longer exists. The snippet below is my first attempt to write a script which will open up a test .docx file, get the reference and remove it and then save the document.

```
$ass = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll")
$thisDocURL = "http://sptest/csite/testlib/tst.docx"
$web = get-spweb -identity "http://sptest/csite"

  $file = $web.GetFileOrFolderObject($thisDocURL)
  $Binary = $File.OpenBinarystream()
  $wpdoc = [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument]::Open($Binary,$True)
  $settings = $wpdoc.maindocumentpart.DocumentSettingsPart
  $URI = $settings.GetExternalRelationship("rId1")
  $URIpath = $uri.uri.AbsoluteURI
  $URIpath.Remove(0,96)
  $wpdoc.Close()
```

Everything works fine with the above code except the end bit. I am able to locate the old server reference in the $URIpath variable and I’m able to clear it with the replace() method. But I can’t save the removal and can’t overwrite the original document. Microsoft in their documentation seems to be suggesting that the close() should save everything but that is not the case. Am I missing something here. Do I need to do some kind of save of the part itself prior to the final save of the document. Or is this more complex than it seems. For instance, do I need to save it back in binary form given that I opened it that way? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps WebDav is doing something funny, have you considered a temp download, edit and then upload with overwrite?

Comment: I did think of doing it that way but I was hoping to learn how to do it with a direct open and save.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.referencerelationship.uri%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the AbsoluteUri property is read-only (the Uri property itself is).
You'd need to try another route, that is deleting the ExternalRelationship:

```
$settings = $wpdoc.maindocumentpart.DocumentSettingsPart
  $settings.DeleteExternalRelationship("rId1")
  $wpdoc.Close()

  $file.Update();
```

As a side note, your code ($URIpath = $uri.uri.AbsoluteURI; $URIpath.Remove(0,96)) doesn't throw exceptions (and doesn't do anything), because you didn't assign the result of the Remove method to anything. Strings are immutable, you would have had to assign it back to the AbsolutURI property, which, I think (I'm not a Powershell expert), would have thrown an exception

Comment: Thanks the DeleteExternalRelationship
has got rid of the template path but there is still a problem with saving the change because when I run script again it comes back.

Comment: @user25207 you are missing the Update to the underlying SPFile object

Comment: Oops thanks. The file gets updated now but the change still doesn't stick so there must be a step missing which I can't figure out.